# Create shape for drawable

Tags: android, drawable, shapes, android-drawable, xml-drawable

I have `ListView`, and i have a background for the list items:

[image: List item background image]

Is there any way to recreate this background as a `shape` in `drawable` XML? The most outer grey is not part of the item background, it is actually the `ListView`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try following with the values of your choice. It will make the bottom two corners rounded.

**rounded_rectangle.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">   
    <item>
    <shape>
        <gradient android:angle="270" android:endColor="#404040"              android:startColor="#404040" />
        <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#808080" />
        <corners android:bottomLeftRadius="11dp" android:bottomRightRadius="11dp"/>
    </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

then use it as a background to your listitem as follows

```
android:background="@drawable/rounded_rectangle"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this shape drawable:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="#606060"/>
    <stroke android:color="#303030" android:width="2dp" />
</shape>
```

Comment: Thank you! This has two problems: i only want to "border" on the bottom, not on every side. And the two bottom corners should be curved.